# JSON gets shortened if i send Eastern European Characters inside

Tags: c#, json

I hope I can explain my problem well enough.

I have Client application on Android Xamarin that communicates with Server application on Windows desktop.
Communication is based on JSON objects. Everything works until there are some Eastern European characters inside that JSON `(č,š,đ,ž)`.

On client side, when I debug JSON before sending everything looks perfectly normal, but upon receiving that JSON on server side, it is shortened by exactly the number of those EE characters.

For example this JSON should look like this:

```
[
  {
    "UserID": 1,
    "OrderID": "87D99FD1-C101-4F08-966A-039C980FCD61",
    "PLU": "3468",
    "Qty": 1.0,
    "Discount": 0.0,
    "GroupID": 6,
    "GroupName": null,
    "Ext": "PEČENO",
    "ExtID": null,
    "PLUID": null,
    "Name": null,
    "Selected": 0,
    "Total": 0.0
  }
]
```

But because there is `Č` inside, JSON will look like this:

```
[
      {
        "UserID": 1,
        "OrderID": "87D99FD1-C101-4F08-966A-039C980FCD61",
        "PLU": "3468",
        "Qty": 1.0,
        "Discount": 0.0,
        "GroupID": 6,
        "GroupName": null,
        "Ext": "PEČENO",
        "ExtID": null,
        "PLUID": null,
        "Name": null,
        "Selected": 0,
        "Total": 0.0
      }
```

If there are two of those characters `ČČ`, then JSON will be also be shortened by two characters:

```
[
          {
            "UserID": 1,
            "OrderID": "87D99FD1-C101-4F08-966A-039C980FCD61",
            "PLU": "3468",
            "Qty": 1.0,
            "Discount": 0.0,
            "GroupID": 6,
            "GroupName": null,
            "Ext": "PEČČENO",
            "ExtID": null,
            "PLUID": null,
            "Name": null,
            "Selected": 0,
            "Total": 0.0
```

However, if I use `sendData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request);` instead of `sendData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request);` then all of those characters would be replaced by `?` automaticaly, and everything works.

I can replace those characters before sending into some other that are not commonly used, and then convert them back on server side, but I guess that there is better fix than that one.

Client code:

```
public string ConnectLnc(string serverIP, int port, String request)
        {

            try
            {

                TcpClient client = new TcpClient(serverIP, port);

                int byteCount = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(request);
                byte[] sendData = new byte[byteCount];

                var bytesToSend = (request); //TODO:
                var header = BitConverter.GetBytes(bytesToSend.Length);
               
                sendData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request);

                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                stream.Write(header, 0, header.Length);
                stream.Write(sendData, 0, sendData.Length);
                
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                //Header
                var msgHeader = new byte[4];
                var bytesLeft = 4;
                var offset = 0;
                StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
                //

                string ReceivedData;
                using (NetworkStream streamX = client.GetStream())
                {
                   
                    while (bytesLeft > 0)
                        {
                            var bytesRead = stream.Read(msgHeader, offset, bytesLeft);
                            offset += bytesRead;
                            bytesLeft -= bytesRead;
                        }

                        bytesLeft = BitConverter.ToInt32(msgHeader, 0);
                        offset = 0;

                        var fileContents = new byte[bytesLeft];
                    
                    // have to repeat as messages can come in chunks
                        while (bytesLeft > 0)
                        {
                            var bytesRead = stream.Read(fileContents, offset, bytesLeft);
                            offset += bytesRead;
                            bytesLeft -= bytesRead;
                        }

                        //foreach (byte b in fileContents)
                        //{
                        //    if (b.Equals(00))
                        //    {
                        //        break;
                        //    }
                        //    else
                        //    {
                        //        msg.Append(Convert.ToChar(b).ToString());
                        //    }

                        //}

                        ReceivedData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileContents);
                    }
                client.Close();
                return ReceivedData;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            //TODO:LOG here

            }
            return "Error";
        }
```

Server Code:

```
private void StartLncListener()
{

    IPAddress myIP = IPAddress.Parse(Globals.MOX_IP);
    TcpListener server = new TcpListener(myIP, Globals.MOX_PORT);
    TcpClient client = default(TcpClient);
    
    try
    {

        server.Start();
        SetText("Server is Active - IP[" + Globals.MOX_IP + ":" + Globals.MOX_PORT + "] - (" + DateTime.Now + ")");
        SetText("Waiting for Connection... ");

    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {

        if (ex.ErrorCode == 10049)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("IP error " + Globals.MOX_IP.ToString() + ":" + Globals.MOX_PORT.ToString()
                            + "\n Check IP!");
            return;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exx)
    {
        //TODO:Create Logging
        MessageBox.Show(exx.ToString());
    }
    while (true)
    {
        var header = new byte[4];
        var bytesLeft = 4;
        var offset = 0;

        // if (Globals.COMMSTATUS == "ERROR") { Globals.COMMSTATUS = "OK"; return; }
        client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
        //byte[] receivedBuffer = new byte[1024];
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        
        while (bytesLeft > 0)
        {
            var bytesRead = stream.Read(header, offset, bytesLeft);
            offset += bytesRead;
            bytesLeft -= bytesRead;

        }

        bytesLeft = BitConverter.ToInt32(header, 0);
        offset = 0;

        var fileContents = new byte[bytesLeft];
       
        // have to repeat as messages can come in chunks
        while (bytesLeft > 0)
        {
            var bytesRead = stream.Read(fileContents, offset, bytesLeft);
            offset += bytesRead;
            bytesLeft -= bytesRead;

        }

        //foreach (byte b in fileContents)
        //{
        //    if (b.Equals(00))
        //    {
        //        break;
        //    }
        //    else
        //    {
        //        msg.Append(Convert.ToChar(b).ToString());
        //    }

        //}
        string msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileContents);


        if (Globals.LOGENABLED == 0)
        {
            var commLogs = LoggingFilter(msg.ToString());
            if (commLogs != String.Empty) { SetText(commLogs); }
        }
        else
        {
            SetText("EXEC " + msg.ToString());
        }

        var ReturnedData = DecodeData(msg.ToString());

        int byteCount = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(ReturnedData);
        byte[] responseMsg = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ReturnedData);


        //var bytesToSend = (responseMsg);
        var respHeader = BitConverter.GetBytes(responseMsg.Length);
        stream.Write(respHeader, 0, respHeader.Length);
        stream.Write(responseMsg, 0, responseMsg.Length);

    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: i seems you are sending in the client `var header = BitConverter.GetBytes(bytesToSend.Length);` as the byte count were really it should be `var header = BitConverter.GetBytes(sendData.Length);`

Comment: Yes, thank you! If you can create answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are sending in the client `var header = BitConverter.GetBytes(bytesToSend.Length);` as the byte count were really it should be var `header = BitConverter.GetBytes(sendData.Length);`